# Given a list of thresholds in descending order will the corresponding FPRs and TPRs lists always be in ascending order?

Tags: machine-learning

I've made a series of predictions with a machine learning model. I have a list `y` of labels and a list `p` of predicted probabilities such that `p[i]` is the predicted probability of the entry associated with `y[i]`.

With Python's `sklearn` library I ran

```
fprs, tprs, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, p)
```

`thresholds` is a list in descending order of decision thresholds, while `fprs` and `tprs` is the list of associated false positive rates and true positive rates where `fprs[i]` and `tprs[i]` are the respective rates given the decision threshold at `thresholds[i]`.

My question is, given that `thresholds` is in descending order, will `fprs` and `tprs` be guaranteed to be in ascending order? I believe that as the decision threshold decreases, more and more probabilities will be marked positive, thus both rates will increase monotonically.

But I've been wrong before about things that seem obvious to me, and I'm writing a tool that must assume these lists will be sorted in ascending order, so I'd like to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [sklearn Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html): roc_curve returns fpr and tpr, which are increasing; and thresholds which is decreasing. Also check the examples below the definitions.